# Does WebSphere 9 support Java 9?

Tags: java, websphere

I have an EAR built in Java 8 and it works perfectly in WAS 9, but if I compile in Java 9, the EAR doesn't work and throws errors like these:

```
[17/05/22 16:19:56:214 CDT] 000000ad wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [ WEB-INF/classes/com/ibatis/sqlmap/engine/mapping/sql/dynamic/DynamicSql.class ] in [ H2H.war ]: [ null ]
[17/05/22 16:19:56:214 CDT] 000000ad wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [ WEB-INF/classes/com/back/auditoria/InsertAuditoriaADM.class ] in [ H2H.war ]: [ null ]
[17/05/22 16:19:56:214 CDT] 000000ad wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [ WEB-INF/classes/com/back/auditoria/PistasAuditoria.class ] in [ H2H.war ]: [ null ]
[17/05/22 16:19:56:215 CDT] 000000ad wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [ WEB-INF/classes/com/back/auditoria/SecurityPistas.class ] in [ H2H.war ]: [ null ]
[17/05/22 16:19:56:215 CDT] 000000ad wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [ WEB-INF/classes/com/back/auditoria/Variables.class ] in [ H2H.war ]: [ null ]
[17/05/22 16:19:56:215 CDT] 000000ad wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.WARFileAnnotationsDetector locateAnnotations Failed to create class reader for [ WEB-INF/classes/com/back/bd/PFIMonitorBD.class ] in [ H2H.war ]: [ null ]
```

Does WebSphere 9 support Java 9?

Comment: Are you aware that Java 9 is no longer under support (since March 2018), and you shouldn't be using it. In any case, going to https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/websphere-application-server-detailed-system-requirements and following those instructions will show that WebSphere 9 requires Java 8.

Comment: Also [Verify Java SDK version shipped with IBM WebSphere Application Server fix packs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/verify-java-sdk-version-shipped-ibm-websphere-application-server-fix-packs) states Java 8.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkRotteveel. I will make the necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WebSphere Application Server V9 traditional runtime does not run on Java versions after 8. If you want to run on Java 11, 17 or newer then you can use WebSphere Liberty instead.